# How to access a function in typescript?

Tags: typescript, sahi

I have written a code to calculate the today's date

```js
function today() {
   const now = new Date();
   const monthday = ("0" + now.getDate().toString()).slice(-2);
   const month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1).toString()).slice(-2);
   const year = now.getFullYear();

   return `${monthday}.${month}.${year}`;
}
```

*I am accessing this with name 'today' to check if the present date exists , but failing to do so*

`await _assertExists(_cell(today, _under(_tableHeader("Calculate"))`

Error is as below

> semantic error TS2345: Argument of type '() => string' is not
> assignable to parameter of type 'AccessorIdentifier'.   Type '() =>
> string' has no properties in common with type
> 'Partial<AccessorIdentifierAttributesWithClassName &
> AccessorIdentifierAttributesWithSahiIndex &
> AccessorIdentifierAttrbutesWithText>

Comment: What's `_cell` definition? Does it expect a string as the first parameter? It looks like it expects `AccessorIdentifier` and not a String.

Comment: _cell is itself a accessor identifier and it expects a string

Comment: Try this: `await _assertExists(_cell(today(), _under(_tableHeader("Calculate"))`

the () after the name `today` tell typescript that today is a fonction to execute

Comment: To see the difference between `today` and `today()` use a console.log(). `console.log(today)` will display the definition of the function. `console.log(today())` will display the data returned by the function